# L5.1 Where To Store DB Connection For Package?

Tags: database, laravel, package, database-connection

In my package, I've own config file and database connection file. Merging config with the app config is quit simple, publishing data migration files too. But how can I merge the database connection file in my Service Provider with the *app /config/database.php*?

/packages/el/adm4y/src/config/database.php

```
return [
   'connections' => [
       'adm4y' => [
           'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_ADM4Y_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_ADM4Y_DATABASE', ''),
            'username' => env('DB_ADM4Y_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_ADM4Y_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
        ]
    ]
];
```